# what new Array(20) actually do

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here i have a Store constructor which has a property named arr which is created using new Array(height*width) provided height and length were sent as arguments to Store constructor.What i know is new Array(20) will create an array which can contain 20 elements.

The Store constructor has a prototype property which uses a map array and fill this.arr of the new Store instance.

But surprisingly the array length gets extended after the fill up process.It becomes 40.I know push method insert elements at the end of an array.Does it mean the array was already has 20 elements.**But it supposed to be empty** ,right?? i am confused!!!

```js
var map=['d d d d d ',
         'e e e e e ']
function Store(width,height){
    this.width=width;
 this.height=height;
 this.arr=new Array(this.width*this.height);
}
Store.prototype.set=function(map){
    for(i=0;i<this.height;i++){
     for(j=0;j<this.width;j++){
      this.arr.push(map[i][j]);
  }
 }
}
var store=new Store(map[0].length,map.length);
document.write('previously : '+store.arr.length+'</br>');
store.set(map);
document.write('now : '+store.arr.length);
```

Comment: `new Array(20)` does not create an array "which can hold up to 20 items", but an empty array with its `.length` initialised to `20`. However, `.push()` will always only *append* new items at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an Array, with `Array` constructor, it creates a sparse Array with the length specified. So when you say `Array(20)` it has created an Array with 20 elements (by changing the `length` property), which are not defined yet, in it. So, lets say that the length is set to 5 and you are trying to access the element at 0. Now, JavaScript will look for the property `0` in the Array object and it will not find anything. So, it will return `undefined`. But when you do something like `array[0] = 1`, it assigns the property `0`, the value 1. So the next time when you look for `array[0]`, it will return 1. Practically, when you simply create an Array, there is nothing in it.

Regarding the `push`, quoting from [MDN's `Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Summary),

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

So, it has been extending the array whenever you are pushing something to it. You might want to  do something like this

```
this.arr[i][j] = map[i][j];
```

Comment: so what happens when i create an array suppose new Array(5).What are the 5 elements of that array??It is an empty array,isn't it??

Comment: @user3138436 That would not be an empty array. It would be an array with 5 `undefined` values.

Comment: @E_net4: No, it really is an empty array (with `.length == 5`)

Comment: @Bergi well yes, from the fact that no values are set in the array.

Comment: @E_net4: I mean in the sense that there are *not* 5 `undefined` values created that are sitting around, but that the array has really no properties (except for the `length`)

Comment: @user3138436 I have included some more explanation, please check.

Answer (score 1):

`new Array(20)` creates an array with 20 elements that are undefined. But the very storage within the array is preallocated. This is considered to be a more efficient way of handling arrays. If you know the array length in advance, always use this approach. (By the way, it is even more beneficial to have all the elements of the array to be of the same type)

In case you preallocate an array, do not push elements to it. Assign values to elements within the array, like this:

```js
var map=['d d d d d ',
         'e e e e e ']
function Store(width,height){
    this.width=width;
 this.height=height;
 this.arr=new Array(this.width*this.height);
}
Store.prototype.set=function(map){
    for(i=0;i<this.height;i++){
     for(j=0;j<this.width;j++){
      this.arr[i*j+j] = map[i][j];
  }
 }
}
var store=new Store(map[0].length,map.length);
document.write('previously : '+store.arr.length+'</br>');
store.set(map);
document.write('now : '+store.arr.length);
```

If you do not know the array size in advance, create an empty zero length array, and `push` (or `unshift`, `push` puts an element to the last position in the array, `unshift` puts the element to the first, 0 index, position in the array) elements to it. This works slower, because each push or unshift will dynamically change the size of the array.